# Items se repetindo em uma RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Tenho um `fragment v4` que é gerenciado por uma `SectionsPagerAdapter`. No `fragment` tenho uma `RecyclerView` que tem um `Adapter` personalizado que recebe uma `ArrayList` que contém exatamente 96 objetos, que representa as horas do dia, ex: posição 0 = 00:00, 1 = 00:15, 2 = 00:30,  3 = 00:45, 4 = 01:00, e assim por diante até 96 = 23:45. Além da hora em si, ele tem também um campo `nome` e outro `procedimentos`. Esses campos só serão preenchidos se tiver alguém agendado para o horário, caso contrario são `""`.

O problema é que ele esta embaralhando tudo na hora de montar o adapter! Um horário ele repete em vários lugares aleatórios que não tem nunguem agendado... pelo que percebi no `log`, conforme faz o `scroll` na `recyclerView`, ela atualiza o `adapter` automaticamente... acho que é isso que esta `bug`... mas não sei como resolver...

Notem na imagem abaixo, deveria ter aparecido o valor somente na posição 01:45, mas aparece também na 00:30, detalhe que nessa posição da `ArrayList` o campo nome esta vazio.

[image: print da lista]

Estou 2 dias tentando achar o problema mas não consegui... deve ser algo bobo que não estou percebendo =(

segue os codigos:

Fragment

```
public class FragmentAgenda extends Fragment {
private static MVP.Presenter presenter;
private View rootView;
private AdapterHorarios adapterHorarios;

public static FragmentAgenda newInstance(int sectionNumber, String dataInicial) {
    FragmentAgenda fragment = new FragmentAgenda();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    args.putString(ARG_DATA_CONSULTA, dataInicial);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_agenda, container, false);
    this.dad = (AgendaActivity) getContext();

    if (presenter == null)
        presenter = new Presenter();
    presenter.setView(this, getContext());
    presenter.retrieveAgendaDia(getArguments(), savedInstanceState);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    initViews();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    getArguments().putParcelableArrayList(KEY_CONSULTAS, presenter.getConsultas());
    getArguments().putParcelableArrayList(KEY_HORARIOS, presenter.getHorarios());
}

private void initViews() {
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.containerHorario);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    adapterHorarios = new AdapterHorarios(getActivity(), presenter.getHorarios(), presenter);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterHorarios);
}

@Override
public void upRecyclerView() {
    adapterHorarios.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Presenter

```
public class Presenter extends PresenterDad implements MVP.Presenter {
private MVP.Model model;
private MVP.View view;
private Context contexto;
private ArrayList<Consulta> consultas;
private ArrayList<Consulta> horarios;
private String mesAno;

public Presenter() {
    this.model = new Model(this);
    this.consultas = new ArrayList<>();
    this.horarios = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public Context getContext() {
    return contexto;
}

@Override
public void setView(MVP.View view, Context context) {
    this.view = view;
    this.contexto = context;
}

@Override
public void retrieveAgendaDia(Bundle args, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String dia = String.valueOf(args.getInt(MVP.View.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    mesAno = args.getString(MVP.View.ARG_DATA_CONSULTA);

    if (args.getParcelableArrayList(MVP.View.KEY_CONSULTAS) != null) {
        horarios = args.getParcelableArrayList(MVP.View.KEY_HORARIOS);
        consultas = args.getParcelableArrayList(MVP.View.KEY_CONSULTAS);
        String data = String.format(dia, mesAno);
        model.montarHorarios(horarios, consultas, data);
        return;
    }
    model.retrieveAgendaDia(consultas, dia, mesAno);
}

@Override
public ArrayList<Consulta> getHorarios() {
    return horarios;
}

@Override
public ArrayList<Consulta> getConsultas() {
    return consultas;
}

@Override
public void upRecyclerView() {
    view.upRecyclerView();
}
}
```

Model

```
public class Model implements MVP.Model {
private final MVP.Presenter presenter;
private final ConsultaCtrl consultaCtrl;

public Model(Presenter presenter) {
    this.presenter = presenter;
    this.consultaCtrl = new ConsultaDAO();
}

@Override
public void retrieveAgendaDia(final ArrayList<Consulta> consultas, final String dia, final String mesAno) {
    consultaCtrl.retriveList(consultas, dia, mesAno, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void result(boolean b) {
            if (b) {
                String data = String.format(Locale.GERMAN, "%02d/%s", Integer.valueOf(dia), mesAno);
                montarHorarios(presenter.getHorarios(), consultas, data);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void montarHorarios(ArrayList<Consulta> horarios, ArrayList<Consulta> consultas, String dataConsulta) {
    if (horarios.size() < 96) {
        horarios.clear();
        int hora = 0, flagHora = 0;
        int minuto = -15;

        for (int id = 0; id <= 95; id++) {
            if ((flagHora - 4) == 0) {
                hora++;
                flagHora = 1;
            } else flagHora++;

            if (minuto >= 45) minuto = 0;
            else minuto += 15;

            String data = String.format("%s %s:%s",
                    dataConsulta,
                    String.format(Locale.GERMAN, "%02d", hora),
                    String.format(Locale.GERMAN, "%02d", minuto)
            );
            horarios.add(new Consulta(hora, minuto, data.replace("-", "/")));
        }

        for (Consulta c : consultas) {
            for (int i = 0; i < horarios.size(); i++) {
                if (horarios.get(i).getDataConsulta().equals(c.getDataConsulta())) {
                    horarios.set(i, c);
                    i = horarios.size();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    presenter.upRecyclerView();
}
}
```

Adapter

```
public class AdapterHorarios extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorariosViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<Consulta> consultas;
private Context contexto;

public AdapterHorarios(Context contexto, ArrayList<Consulta> consultas, MVP.Presenter presenter) {
    this.consultas = consultas;
    this.presenter = presenter;
    this.contexto = contexto;
}

@Override
public HorariosViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater
            .from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.adapter_agenda, parent, false);
    return new HorariosViewHolder( view );
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(HorariosViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.setDados(consultas.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return consultas.size();
}
}
```

Holder

```
public class HorariosViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
private TextView hora, nomePaciente, procedimentos;
private ImageView staus;

public HorariosViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    staus = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.check);
    nomePaciente = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nomePaciente);
    procedimentos = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.procedimentos);
    hora = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hora);
}

public void setDados(Consulta consulta){
    if (consulta.getNomePaciente() != null){
        staus.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_checked);
        nomePaciente.setText(consulta.getNomePaciente());
        procedimentos.setText(consulta.getDataConsulta());
    }
    hora.setText(Datas.formatHoraConsulta(consulta.getHoraConsulta(), consulta.getMinutoConsulta())); // retorna hora ex: "07:15"
}
}
```

Comment: No método `setDados()`, de HorariosViewHolder, o `if` não deveria ter um `else`?

Comment: Era exatamente isso... Faltou o else. Achei o problema as 4 dá manhã de hoje! Rsrs por algum motivo ele estava pegando lixo dos textViews. Colocando o else e preenchendo os campos em branco resolveu o problema de ficar repetindo. Mas agora apareceu outro. Agora quando se deslisa para a pager vizinha, os dados se repetem igual dá view anterior, mas o Arraylist é diferente! Tô quase abandonado o SectionsPagerAdapter e usar um FragmentManager mesmo...

Comment: É melhor colocar outra pergunta para esse novo problema. Coloque o código do SectionsPagerAdapter e como está a fazer o alternar entre ArrayList's

Comment: Ok. Vou criar outro tópico. Só uma pergunta, posso criar uma nova pergunta e colocar esse tópico como link e dizer que a pergunta é derivada deste?

Comment: Pode, no entanto coloque nela o código relevante para esse problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O RecyclerView.Adapter implementa o padrão "View Holder" recorrendo à classe RecyclerView.ViewHolder usando-a nos métodos `onCreateViewHolder()` e `onBindViewHolder()`, permitindo que uma view anteriormente criada possa ser reaproveitada.

É da sua responsabilidade, no método `onBindViewHolder()`, retornar essa view preenchida com os valores correspondentes ao item da RecyclerView em causa.

O método que estar a ser usado para esse efeito é o `setDados()` de HorariosViewHolder.
No entanto, ele só actualiza a view quando `consulta.getNomePaciente() != null`.
Quando não é esse o caso, a view é retorna sem alteração(apenas `hora` é actualizada), ela tem valores de um item anteriormente usado.

Deve alterar o método de forma a que as duas situações sejam tratadas.

```
public void setDados(Consulta consulta){
    if (consulta.getNomePaciente() != null){
        staus.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_checked);
        nomePaciente.setText(consulta.getNomePaciente());
        procedimentos.setText(consulta.getDataConsulta());
    }else{
        staus.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_checked);//ou outra, não sei
        nomePaciente.setText("");
        procedimentos.setText("");
    }
    hora.setText(Datas.formatHoraConsulta(consulta.getHoraConsulta(), consulta.getMinutoConsulta())); // retorna hora ex: "07:15"
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado por esclarecer o porquê isso ocorre... Não sabia que viewHolder reaproveitava view já criadas anteriormente. Agora entendi o problema!

Comment: A intenção da resposta foi essa, explicar o porquê, já que no comentário não havia espaço para isso.